# javafx test run fail in netbeans

Tags: java, javafx

i started to develop an app with javafx framework a week ago and i tested it by running the project (simple F6 "Project Run" in Netbeans 11.0 on win10).

everything was fine until today when i added a new FXML and database codes related to it. the project compiles successfully but when it (netbeans or me) executes the jar file, things get weird! one empty icon shows up in taskbar and laptop fan speed increases.

i'm sure sth is wrong with my code but i can't know which part. can anyone help me with suggesting a realtime debugger so i can know the source of crash?

Comment: [mcve] please .. fan speed (and noise :) increases usually means a heavy-load (background) thread running wild .. and is not really answerable from afar.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer eventually. it was a try and catch block which was trying to load an fxml which couldn't be loaded and i wrote this block inside initialize method :) but i wonder why the catch block didn't throw any exceptions.